# Increment on an array doesn't go passed 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

So I'm creating a pagination in jquery with bootstrap. My HTML works fine because I used it with a more ugly, lengthier code involving 200 or so lines of calling functions. I'm trying to avoid that, hence the array.

After page 2, the entire code doesn't work, and I have no idea why. I've simplified it to the greatest degree, and even tested it without any jquery and alerted the number to use from the array, and what string the array is using.

```
var paginationTable = ['#p1-g1','#p2-g1','#p3-g1','#p4-g1','#p5-g1', // All spicer pages
                       '#p1-g2','#p2-g2','#p3-g2','#p4-g2','#p5-g2', // All saginaw pages
                       '#p1-g3','#p2-g3','#p3-g3','#p4-g3','#p5-g3', // All toyota pages
                       '#p1-g4','#p2-g4','#p3-g4','#p4-g4','#p5-g4']; // All borg-warner pages
var pageNum = 0;
var tabNum = paginationTable[pageNum];     
function productInfo(button, productPage) {
    $(button).click(function(){
        $(productPage).show(200);
    });
    $('#next').click(function(){
        pageNum++;
        tabNum = paginationTable[pageNum];
    });
    $('#previous').click(function(){
        pageNum = pageNum - 1;
        tabNum = paginationTable[pageNum];
    });
    $('.arrayNumber').click(function(){
        alert(tabNum + ' and ' + pageNum);
    });
};
```

Thats my testing code. It works 100% right now. when I click the button to use '.arrayNumber' click function, it will display the pageNum and the tabNum correctly. For instance, it will display #p1-g1 and 0 and then when I do #next, it will display #p2-g1 and 1. It will keep doing that. Therefore it works just fine.

However as soon as I the jQuery to it, it all falls apart.

```
var paginationTable = ['#p1-g1','#p2-g1','#p3-g1','#p4-g1','#p5-g1', // All spicer pages
                       '#p1-g2','#p2-g2','#p3-g2','#p4-g2','#p5-g2', // All saginaw pages
                       '#p1-g3','#p2-g3','#p3-g3','#p4-g3','#p5-g3', // All toyota pages
                       '#p1-g4','#p2-g4','#p3-g4','#p4-g4','#p5-g4']; // All borg-warner pages
var pageNum = 0;
var tabNum = paginationTable[pageNum];     
function productInfo(button, productPage) {
    $(button).click(function(){
        $(productPage).show(200);
    });
    $('#next').click(function(){
        pageNum++;
        tabNum = paginationTable[pageNum];
        $('.section-info').hide(200);
        $(tabNum).show(300);
    });
    $('#previous').click(function(){
        pageNum = pageNum - 1;
        tabNum = paginationTable[pageNum];
        $('.section-info').hide(200);
        $(tabNum).show(300);
    });
    $('.arrayNumber').click(function(){
        alert(tabNum + ' and ' + pageNum);
    });
};
```

Everything works when I did it the long-winded method of jquery involving a bunch of classes and functions. Therefore my HTML and CSS aren't conflicting it. I've looked over my HTML a hundred times over, so I don't think its my HTML. Heres the HTML anyway:

```
<div class="section-content use-bootstrap">
            <h1>Spicer, Saginaw, Toyota, Borg-Warner Type CV Components</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a id="g1">Spicer <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a></li>
                <li><a id="g2">Saginaw <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a></li>
                <li><a id="g3">Toyota <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a></li>
                <li><a id="g4">Borg-Warner <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a></li>
                <li><a id="g5">Close Menus <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg arrayNumber"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> Array Number</a>
            <!-- ITEM LIST FOR SPICER -->
                <div id="p1-g1" class="section-info">
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 1</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 1</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 1</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 1</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 1</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a id="previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                    <li><a id="next">Next Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="p2-g1" class="section-info">
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 2</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a id="previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                    <li><a id="next">Next Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="p3-g1" class="section-info">
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 3</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a id="previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                    <li><a id="next">Next Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="p4-g1" class="section-info">
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 4</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a id="previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                    <li><a id="next">Next Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="p5-g1" class="section-info">
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name. 5</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="section-product">
                        <h1><small>This is the product's name.</small></h1>
                        <p>The description of the product.</p>
                        <a href="#">Item Page</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a id="previous">Previous Page</a></li>
                    <li><a id="next">Next Page</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

What is causing this issue? The code works until you get to page 2 or in terms of the array '#p2-g1 and 1'. When I try to get to '#p3-g1 and 2', nothing happens. Its like the script is hanging. Nothing outputs in console, and nothing increments. The code is set up to increment before anything happens, therefore I should be able to click .arrayNumber button and alert out the values. The values still output #p2-g1 and 1 even though the incrementing should have been ran.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle.net that demonstrates this perhaps?

Comment: I'm currently on the clock, so it might take me awhile to get around to that. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually something bizarre and strange. I had the "next" and "previous" buttons contained in each hidden div. They all contain #next and #previous which in theory wouldn't matter if the buttons are switch because the script itself is only listening to those tags. However, once I moved the button away from each individial page and set inside the div that contains each page, it works. There must be something in Jquery that affects the DOM element structure and what it listens to despite that fact that all of those buttons contain virtually the same attribute.

I don't quite understand it myself, but tl;dr, the fix was just putting the next and previous buttons somewhere else. My code works perfectly, so for the one person who attempted to help me, thank you. For the one person who downvoted this question, well, I hope your day sucks.